Where can I find structural information about my metal garage kit?
I am based in Europe and would like to assemble a Metal Garage of the type you purchase in kit form.
My architect asked me to provide structural information.  Any help from where I can find this information.
**I want to clarify that I posted here simply because I asked two suppliers but only got assembly instructions.  The assembly instructions did not specify this data.
Is it that I am the only person who has ever raised this questions.  If anyone here knows of a company that can provide this information and ships to Europe please contact me through DM.
**

From the maker of the metal garage.  They should supply all information and structural specs needed, including any foundation details for the building.

Please see [ask]. Your question is too broad. It does seem obvious that the manufacturer would provide this, though.

The only place to get that info is from the manufacturer of the kit.  You need to chose the kit first or ask for the info from the manufacturers you are considering. Provide that to your architect, then make a choice.

I would agree 100%; I asked two companies but all I got was assembly instructions.  I find it weird. The reason I cam here was primarily to see whether others (including those who have been kind enough to comment) whether they asked for this information and if you got it.

@chribonn,  Tell the companies you need this information before considering a purchase.   Many times the person getting the request, pays no attention to what you are actually asking for.

What really surprises me is that many speak the virtues of these structures without any solid understanding of what they are acquiring. The fact that suppliers do not quote such information as standard in their literature also makes me think.
